# Getting the latest node and npm

Tags: node.js, npm, n

I did `sudo apt install nodejs` and then checked my versions and I'm on version 8, which is a bit old.

I did `sudo npm install -g n` and then `n latest` and it says it has version 11 active, but then `node --version` spits out 8 again.

What gives?

Comment: Okay, removed the nodejs one, and then latest took over. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update you repository source for node by issuing this commands on your terminal:

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nvm` the Node version manager  (https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Answer (score 0):

`n` installs to `/usr/local` by default. Presumably `apt` installs to a different directory which is earlier in your `PATH`, so its version gets found first.

Removing the system installed `node` (as you did) since you are using `n` to manage `node` is simple, or edit your PATH to put `/usr/local/bin` before the other location.

Additional logging has been added to `n` in v6.0.0 to help recognise this setup issue, so hopefully will be less confusing in future.

If available, you can use `which -a node` to see all the locations that `node` is found in the `PATH`.